# Option+Left in Bash on Mac sometimes produces ;9D

Tags: bash, macos, readline, iterm2

I've set up my bash in iTerm2 on Mac so that Option+Left goes backward a word, and Option+Right goes forward a word. I've done this to have a similar setup as on my Linux machine.

However, sometimes the setup stops working, and when I press Option+Left, the cursor doesn't jump a word backwards, but adds the string `;9D` to the command line input. Option+Right then adds `;9C`.

When open a new terminal, Option+Left/Right work correctly, only sometimes this incorrect behavior occurs. I have not yet figured out what causes this. Typing `reset` does not fix the issue, re-loading my bash config with `source .bashrc` doesn't fix the issue either.

My questions are:

1. What is causing the Option+Left/Right shortcuts from working sometimes?
2. How can I fix this so it doesn't happen again?

This is my `.inputrc`:

```
"\e\e[D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
```

Possibly relevant iTerm2 settings:
[image: Remap Modifiers Setting]
[image: Keys in Profile Setting]

Comment: Sounds like this might be specific to iTerm. If so, you might have better chances of getting an answer over at [apple.se]. If you decide to ask there, please remember to delete this one first.

Comment: Thanks for the Ask Different suggestion. So far I don't know if it's a bash or iTerm problem.

Comment: This will always depend on the terminal you are using, so it is almost certainly an iTerm issue. Different terminals understand different escape sequences in `.inputrc` for some reason I don't know. Does adding (without removing the ones you already have) `"\e[5D": backward-word` and `"\e[5C": forward-word` help?

Comment: @terdon I've added your suggestions to my `.inputrc`, thanks. I can not tell yet if it worked or not, as my problem only happens sporadically.